# Remotely called VBScript fails, but works when run locally

Tags: vbscript, ado, psexec

I've been using *PSExec.exe* to run a *vbscript* on a few hundred remote virtual machines.  This is generally working.  However, on a small group of VM's, I get this error:

> MyScriptName.vbs(24, 5) WScript.CreateObject: Could not create object
>   named "ADODB.Connection"

Here is the offending line of code in the vbscript file:

```
Set oConn = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
```

I have tried this (for 64-bit *cscript.exe*):

```
PsExec.exe \\RemoteVMName  -c -h -u MyDomain\MyWinLogin -p MyPwd cscript.exe "\\UncPath\To\My\Script.vbs"
```

And I tried this (for 32-bit *cscript.exe*):

```
PsExec.exe \\RemoteVMName  -c -h -u MyDomain\MyWinLogin -p MyPwd C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe "\\UncPath\To\My\Script.vbs"
```

Curiously, if I log into the remote VM, I can manually run the vbscript file.  It succeeds with no script errors.  What could be causing that vbscript error?

Comment: Why do you think your first line will run 64 bit cscript. My Psexec is 32 bit so any reference to `system32` will get redirected into `SysWoW64`. Use `C:\Windows\SysNative` to refer to System32 in a 32 bit program.

Answer (score 0):

You should include `cmd.exe /c` for executing vbs files with **cscript** over psexec.

You don't need to copy the script file as long as the account can access that UNC path.

```
PsExec.exe \\RemoteVMName -e -h -u MyDomain\MyWinLogin -p MyPwd cmd.exe /c cscript.exe "\\UncPath\To\My\Script.vbs"
```